# Focus textbox after checking checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, checkbox

That's my xaml:

```
<CheckBox Content="Length" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MessageLengthChecked}" x:Name="LengthCheckBox"/>

<TextBox x:Name="LengthTextBox" Text="{Binding Length}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=LengthCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

If the user check the checkbox, the textbox should be focused and the content should be marked. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this is the checked event from your checkbox

```
 LengthTextBox.Focus();
 LengthTextBox.SelectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your controls in a parent container, say grid, and fire a data trigger to set the focused element.

```
    <Grid>
       <Grid.Style>
          <Style>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageLengthChecked}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=LengthTextBox}"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </Grid.Style>

      <CheckBox Content="Length" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MessageLengthChecked}" x:Name="LengthCheckBox"/>

      <TextBox x:Name="LengthTextBox" Text="{Binding Length}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=LengthCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add evente in your XAML for checkBox

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"  Name="myCheckBox"  Checked="myCheckBox_Checked" />
```

By c# code try this:

```
private void myCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked == true)
     {
           myTextBox.Focus();
           myTextBox.SelectAll();
     }
     else
     {
           //TODO
     }
}
```